# Worklight on OS X, iPhone and Android builds fail due to missing info.plist and other files

Tags: android, iphone, ios, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

I am following the step by step "Hello World" guide from IBM located here:
    http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-aim1206-working-with-worklight-1/

I am to the step where you build and deploy the environments, but when I attempt to do so, I get the following errors.

```
FWLST1040E: iphone build failed: com.worklight.builder.exception.WorklightBuildRuntimeException: Resource Manager - Problem reading info.plist file /Users/snip/Documents/workspace-indigo/HelloWorld/apps/HelloWorld/iphone/native/HelloWorldHelloWorldIphone-Info.plist (No such file or directory) Nested exception: /Users/snip/Documents/workspace-indigo/HelloWorld/apps/HelloWorld/iphone/native/HelloWorldHelloWorldIphone-Info.plist (No such file or directory)

FWLST1040E: android build failed: com.worklight.builder.exception.WorklightBuildRuntimeException: Resource Manager - Error while reading XML file: /Users/snip/Documents/workspace-indigo/HelloWorld/apps/HelloWorld/android/native/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory) Nested exception: /Users/snip/Documents/workspace-indigo/HelloWorld/apps/HelloWorld/android/native/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)

A core eclipse exception has occurred: Failed to read project description file from location '/Users/snip/Documents/workspace-indigo/HelloWorld/apps/HelloWorld/android/native/.project'.
```

I have tried the usual suspects in trying to clear this up.

1) Delete the environments native folders and rebuild. (Failed)
2) Delete each entire environment and do the environment additions again (Failed)
3) Did a full project Clean and Build Project on the entire project. (Failed)
4) Restarted eclipse with the -clean option (Failed)

Here is my current Environment:
IDE: Eclipse Indigo Release
WorkLight: 5.0.5100 (Assuming 5.0.0.5?, the plugin versions are weird)
OS: Mac OSX 10.8.2

I find it pretty disheartening that you cannot even follow the Hello World guide without running across some kind of error. This is of course after being handed a mobile application IBM wrote for us in this framework, which we were unsuccessful in getting deployed to Android and IPhone Devices. (We were able to get it running just fine in the WLC Simulators for Android and iPhone, but actually deploying it to the iPhone and Android just results in crashes)

Any Ideas on how to resolve this issue? Is WorkLight an avenue even worth pursuing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I fixed this issue was to completely wipe and redo the environment. This included the following for me.

1) Created a new user on the Mac (I had been using another devs user)
2) Reinstall Eclipse Juno.
3) Create a new workspace
4) Install the Worklight from the Eclipse Market
5) Install the Android ADT and SDK.

This then allowed me to create the environments properly without missing file warnings.