# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Build issues

Tags: eclipse, macos, ibm-mobilefirst

I am just running a test app, and my build fails with the following logs, I have tried restarting, changing workpace, creating test app but dint work. please let me know.

```
ipad build failed: Cannot overwrite template file '/Users/mspssmac-pc232938/Documents/Projects/FnApp/testApp/apps/testApp/ipad/native/Settings.bundle/Root.plist'
[2013-08-23 12:04:10] FWLST1040E: iphone build failed: Cannot overwrite template file '/Users/mspssmac-pc232938/Documents/Projects/FnApp/testApp/apps/testApp/iphone/native/Settings.bundle/Root.plist'
[2013-08-23 12:04:10]             A core eclipse exception has occurred: Failed to read project description file from location '/Users/mspssmac-pc232938/Documents/Projects/FnApp/testApp/apps/testApp/android/native/.project'.
```

Thanks 
djrecker

Comment: Having never seen this issue, my first guess would be something related to permissions. Can you check the permission of the files that in the error messages?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I have already given full access read and write to all the folders and subfolders, again i get the same error. Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try deleting the native folder
- Try running Eclipse with the -clean flag
- Is this a shared workspace between Eclipses? Does it work with a local workspace?
- See if this helps: [Worklight on OS X, iPhone and Android builds fail due to missing info.plist and other files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386910/worklight-on-os-x-iphone-and-android-builds-fail-due-to-missing-info-plist-and)
- You have also asked this here: [IBM Worklight - Build failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946676/ibm-worklight-build-failed)

A common issue for all seems to be:

> A core eclipse exception has occurred: Failed to read project
>   description file from location ... [path to .project file]