# IBM Worklight 6.1 - "Missing .project file" error while trying to build the Android environment

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

After I installed Worklight 6.1 and the Android plug-in and SDK, I got the below exception when trying to build an app:

> [2013-12-13 13:27:07] Starting build process: application 'WorklightTest', all environments
>   [2013-12-13 13:27:10] Failed importing native project for 'Android phones and tablets' Failed to read project description file from location
>   D:\Development\worklight_dev\WorklightTestApp\apps\WorklightTest\android\native.project.
>   [2013-12-13 13:27:10] A core eclipse exception has occurred: Failed to
>   read project description file from location
>   D:\Development\worklight_dev\WorklightTestApp\apps\WorklightTest\android\native.project.

Actually, I did it with worklight 6.0...

Comment: Your are deploying the app created by which version of worklight

Comment: You mention both Worklight 6.0 and 6.1... Do you mean it works for you with 6.0 but not with 6.1? did you try creating a new workspace?

Comment: I tested with Worklight 6.1 and failed it with above exception.And, I already tested same test with Worklight 6.0 without any issue..

Comment: You are not answering my question. Did you try with a new workspace for 6.1? is this a new or existing project?

Comment: I made a new workspace, but it failed with same exception

Comment: `...\android\native.project` doesn't look right. It should have been `...\android\native\.project`

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and on my Windows 7 Machine it was also a Java Install / Version problems as it seems.

I am an IBMer, so I had the IBM Java JRE and SDKs for version 7 installed. Also the Oracle JRE and JDK. Also both for 32bit and 64bit. The command line always referred to the IBM JDK.

Once I removed all the IBM JREs and JDKs and left only the two, Oracle JDK 7-21 in 32bit and 64bit, on my machine, the creation of the Android project was successful.

Comment: Thanks ... this resolved the problem ... I faced this issue with Java 1.8 ... I had to move to 1.7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and got it resolved (under Ubuntu) by updating Java alternative to the same Java SDK (openjdk-7) that is required by Worklight; using:

sudo update-alternatives --config java

Also checked the SDK alternative points to the same:

sudo update-alternatives --config javac

Answer (score 0):

I have ran across this issue many times haven't yet found a solid resolution.  In my latest experience today, this combination of things worked for me consistently for 3 different occurrences on Windows 7

- delete native folder in android environment
- set -vm flag in eclipse.ini to use Oracle JRE
- start eclipse with -clean flag

Answer (score -1):

From: [IBM Worklight 6.0 - Build issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396665/ibm-worklight-6-0-build-issues)

Try to:

- Delete the native folder and build the project again
- Create a new workspace for Eclipse
- [Run Eclipse with the `-clean` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so)

I have installed a fresh copy (not upgraded) of Worklight 6.1, created new project+app+environment and the build passed successfully.

I suggest to try the above suggestions as they are ordered.

Comment: I did it according to your guide..and also, I tried to reinstall eclipse and worklight 6.1 and Android plugin, but it failed...

Comment: Which Eclipse version are you using? Do you have read-write permissions to all of Drive D?